# Associated object does not have a primary key

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, sequel

I still can't find a solution to fix an association factory issue when using Sequel.

I have two models relying on `one_to_many`, which is the same as `has_many`in Active Record, and `many_to_one`, which is the same as `belongs_to` in Active Record.

Here are the defined factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  to_create { |instance| instance.save }
  factory :post do
    title  "some title"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  to_create { |instance| instance.save }
  factory :comment do
    content    "some content"
    association :post, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

When running `build(:comment)`, it fails with:

```
Associated object does not have a primary key.
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that? I can always build/create a post first, then sign it to a comment, but it is tedious. More than that, I'll have to remove `association :post, strategy: :build` and use some Integer random value.

I'm using:

- `factory_girl_rails 4.8.0`
- `ruby 2.4.0`
- `sequel-rails 0.9.15`
- `sequel 4.45.0`

Answer (score 5):

Sequel doesn't supporting adding an associated object to a unsaved object, unless you are using the nested_attributes plugin to create both at the same time.  So unless FactoryGirl has specific code to deal with that, it probably will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your strategy should be create, not build. Here's how I solved it with FactoryBot:

```
after(:build) { |comment| comment.post ||= create(:post) }
```

This will happen by default if you specify the association without any parameters and use this configuration:

```
FactoryBot.use_parent_strategy = false
```